# Excel Conditional Format AND Statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet with the days of the month (in DD/MM/YYYY format) running across row 1 and values in each column downwards that correspond to the day above, with a trigger value in the last column, for example:

`02/01/2000|03/01/2000|trigger`

`1000      |1000      |1100`

`560       |3400      |1000`

Where `02/01/2000` is in `A1`

I'm looking to create a conditional formatting statement to colour cells that have a corresponding row 1 WEEKDAY value of Sunday (7), and if they're lower in value compared to the trigger value for their row.

For example, format `A2:B2` if `A1:B1` is a Sunday and `A2:B2 < C2` which I'd like to format A2 but leave B2 as it doesn't meet the Sunday criteria.

Then format `A3:B3` if `A1:B1` is a Sunday and `A3:B3 < C3` in which A3 is lower than C3 but it's corresponding date above in A1 isn't a Sunday.

I know I can format cells based on their weekday with `=WEEKDAY(A1:B1)=7` and compare values in the row to the trigger value with `=A2:B2=<$C$2` but any attempts to combine the two doesn't seem to work (and without an absolute cell reference for C2, that formula seems to highlight the wrong cells).

I would appreciate any suggestions or help!

Comment: `WEEKDAY(A1:B1)` doesn't seem right and Sunday is 1 not 7 according to the default WEEKDAY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> <sub>format A2:B2 if A1:B1 is a Sunday and A2:B2 < C2 ... Then format A3:B3 if A1:B1 is a Sunday and A3:B3 < C3</sub>

Grab all of column A:B with A1 as the 'active cell' and create a CFR based on this formula,

```
=and(weekday(a$1)=1, a1<c1, row()>1)
```